# Original price in Sales Order not appearing

Tags: magento-1.7

I have Magento 1.7x Installed

I have a concern if someone can guide me if I have setup something wrongly...

I have Product X with Price 100 and Special Price 80

When Customer place the order, it charge custoemr 80 Rs. for obvious reasons but when I look into order through admin panel, it's not showing 100 (which is MRP) anywhere nor customer can see how much discount he got in his order or his "My account" section!

I thought this would be by default functionality available but unfortunately I am not getting it.

Any suggestions will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Hello My friend You are mixed two thing **`Special Price` and `Discount`**.

**`Special Price`** Means When you set the Special price for any product then you can purchase that product on Special price. You are not getting any discount on that product.For [More Details](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/special-price)

In simple words If any product has original price is $12 and set special price set to $10. then user has to paid only $10. so when you add this product to cart then It will take $10 of that product and it will display $10 in checkout as well as `Order Level` in Backend.

**`Discount`** When you create any promotional Rules for catalog as well as cart level then It will be display in `cart, checkout and Order Level` as a `discount`. [More Details](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/what-are-catalog-price-rules-and-how-do-i-use-them)

So what you are show in your Current shop is as Per Magento Standard.

Hope you can understand what I am trying to say.